# Tricky numpy argmax on last dimension of 3-dimensional ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, argmax

if have an array of shape (9,1,3).

```
array([[[  6,  12, 108]],

   [[122, 112,  38]],

   [[ 57, 101,  62]],

   [[119,  76, 177]],

   [[ 46,  62,   2]],

   [[127,  61, 155]],

   [[  5,   6, 151]],

   [[  5,   8, 185]],

   [[109, 167,  33]]])
```

I want to find the argmax index of the third dimension, in this case it would be 185, so index 7.

I guess the solution is linked to reshaping but I can't wrap my head around it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds more like you want `np.argmax(yourarray[:, 0, 2])`.

Comment: It doesn't really make much sense to say "the argmax index of the third dimension".  You could ask for the third coordinate of the argmax (which would be 2, not 7) or the first coordinate, which would be 7, or the argmax of the sliced array after taking [:, 0, 2] (as PP suggested, which is indeed 7).

Comment: I don't get why every item is a singleton list, seems like a bad modeling.

Comment: @PaulPanzer how about `np.argmax(np.max(arr, 2))` ?

Comment: @kmario23 or `np.unravel_index(np.argmax(arr), arr.shape)`? Anything that results in something with a seven in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do it like this:

```
data = np.array([[[  6,  12, 108]],

   [[122, 112,  38]],

   [[ 57, 101,  62]],

   [[119,  76, 177]],

   [[ 46,  62,   2]],

   [[127,  61, 155]],

   [[  5,   6, 151]],

   [[  5,   8, 185]],

   [[109, 167,  33]]])

np.argmax(data[:,0][:,2])
 7
```

Comment: What's `data[:, 0][:, 2]`? Please just do `data[:, 0, 2]` instead of creating an unnecessary intermediate.

Comment: Yeah, very good. But you are not helping by spreading this kind sloppiness.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's tricky about it. But, one way to get the index of the greatest element along the last axis would be by using [`np.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) and [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) like:

```
# find `max` element along last axis 
# and get the index using `argmax` where `arr` is your array
In [53]: np.argmax(np.max(arr, axis=2))
Out[53]: 7
```

Alternatively, as [@PaulPanzer suggested in his comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360189/tricky-numpy-argmax-on-last-dimension-of-3-dimensional-ndarray/#comment83707816_48360189), you could use:

```
In [63]: np.unravel_index(np.argmax(arr), arr.shape)
Out[63]: (7, 0, 2)

In [64]: arr[(7, 0, 2)]
Out[64]: 185
```

Comment: Oh, please don't promote my throw-away comments ;-) Or, if you must use the other one; I think it's better.

Comment: Thank you, trickiness is relative and I haven't spent that much time with np as of yet, although I will in the future.

Comment: @TshoshHarris Sure! but, You don't have to thank explicitly. Upvoting answers, if it was helpful to you, is more than enough in SO.

Comment: @kmario23 You're right, and I do, but you have to get up to 15 Rep until it's visible ;)